# I have a space between the navbar and a section. Can anyone see the error?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a break/margin between the navbar and section1. I'm using bootstrap, and see nothing wrong with either thing. Is there an extra class I need to add in order to remove this space? Does anyone have any idea about what's wrong? Thanks!

```css
h1 {

 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

}

body {

 background-color: black;

}

section.section1 {

 height: 100%;
 background-image: url("images/background3.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
 background-size: cover;

}



.title-div {

 position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;

}

.title {

 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 7vw;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.typed-cursor{

    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    color: white;
 font-size: 7vw;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
@keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<html>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/typed.js"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

 <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  

 </head>

 <body>

 <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
         <div class = "container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            
                 <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">Cotton Fencing</a>
                
                 <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            
           </button>
          </div>
        
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             
                  <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                  
                                  
              </ul>
          </div>
         </div>
        
 </div>

  <section class="section1" id="section1">
   <div class="title-div">
    
    <script>
      $(function(){
          $(".element").typed({
            strings: ["Beautiful. ^700", "Easy. ^700", "Cheap. ^700", "Cotton Fencing."],
            typeSpeed: 0
          });


      });


    </script>
    

    <span class="element title"></span>
    <span id="typed-cursor"></span>
    

   </div>
  </section>

 </body>

 

</html>
```

**UPDATED** Here is a picture of what it looks like. FYI, the background is set to black.

[image: What it looks like]

**UPDATE 2** Thank you so much for everyone to helped! Thanks to Mike Barwick for finding the error. I think we were all thinking too hard about this and the answer was obvious. Thanks again for all your help though!

Comment: `.navbar { margin-bottom: 0; }` - Also when you are asking for help on Bootstrap I found this site that load Bootstrap and lets you apply your changes. It will help people that are trying to help you. http://www.bootply.com/

Comment: Okay thanks @kel is it kind of like JSFiddle but with Bootstrap loaded in?

Comment: No problem and yeah, looks like a Bootstrap version of JSFiddle (It's not mine, I just found it in a search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This WILL WORK (I think lol)...based on your image.

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot. Thanks so much! This worked. I guess I was trying to think to complicatedly.

Comment: Everyone was getting too complicated and using selectors far down the CSS tree lol. Once I saw the image...it was obvious. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Yup.  It's the margin on your `ul`.  Add a CSS rule like `ul.nav.navbar-right { margin: 0; }` and watch it disappear.

## Edit just for proof:

```css
/* Add this line */
ul.nav.navbar-right {
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {

 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

}

body {

 background-color: black;

}

section.section1 {

 height: 100%;
 background-image: url("images/background3.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
 background-size: cover;

}



.title-div {

 position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;

}

.title {

 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 7vw;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.typed-cursor{

    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    color: white;
 font-size: 7vw;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
@keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink{
    0% { opacity:1; }
    50% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<html>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/typed.js"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

 <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  

 </head>

 <body>

 <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
         <div class = "container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            
                 <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">Cotton Fencing</a>
                
                 <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            
           </button>
          </div>
        
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             
                  <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                  
                                  
              </ul>
          </div>
         </div>
        
 </div>

  <section class="section1" id="section1">
   <div class="title-div">
    
    <script>
      $(function(){
          $(".element").typed({
            strings: ["Beautiful. ^700", "Easy. ^700", "Cheap. ^700", "Cotton Fencing."],
            typeSpeed: 0
          });


      });


    </script>
    

    <span class="element title"></span>
    <span id="typed-cursor"></span>
    

   </div>
  </section>

 </body>

 

</html>
```

Comment: Still there, any other ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's actually bothered by the "line break". So these consecutive elements need `display: block;`.

Comment: It's so weird it doesn't work. I have posted a picture of what it looks like.

Comment: @MatejNanut to which elements would I need to add `display:block`?

Comment: Well, the `<div>` elements next to each other. The ones with classes `.navbar-header` and `.navbar-collapse`. But it seems like a hack. I think there must be a cleaner way to do what you want with Bootstrap. EDIT: Nevermind, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.nav.navbar-right ul { 
   margin: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Still there, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Or "margin-top:0;"
Margin can defined like "margin: 0 0 0 0;
The first number is top, the second right, third: bottom, fourth: left

Greets

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change the margin of the ul to 0

```
.nav .navbar-right ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

That should fix it! :)